# How to disable auto-compile after saving ~/.emacs file?

Tags: init-file

My system: Debian GNU/Linux (Jessie)

My Emacs: GNU Emacs 24.1, installed from Debian package

I found that when I saved ~/.emacs for any change, Emacs started to compile files into .elc under ~/.emacs.d/elpa directory.  It didn't take much time but it's annoying.

I had all my Emacs setting and package in a Git repository.  Is that the cause of the auto-compiling behavior?

How to disable it?

Comment: That is rather odd.  I've never heard of any such auto-compile feature.  I do not experience this behavior with Emacs 24.5 on Arch Linux and my Emacs directory is also a Git repository.  Do you still experience this when starting Emacs with the -Q option?

Comment: This would constitute a bug, as init-files shouldn't be compiled. Please consider a bug-report.

Comment: I'm not sure the init files are being compiled. It sounds like the package files are being compiled whenever the init files are modified. The OP doesn't say that the init files are being compiled though.

Comment: Like Qudit said, this is not default behavior. Please try start Emacs with the command `emacs -q`, and see if that still happens. If it doesn't, then it's being caused by something in your init file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a package installed or a function defined that is auto-compiling *el* files on save. As recommended by others check your *init* file, installed packages and also your *hooks*.

Comment: I copied some init config from the Net and didn't notice that part of the config let my Emacs auto-compiling on save.  The problem solved after I deleted these lines.